# Why am I not able to grab from the url?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web = requests.get("http://minewind.com/forums", allow_redirects=False)

mems = BeautifulSoup(web.text)
mems.prettify()

for links in mems.find_all('a'):
    print (links.get("href"))
```

I'm trying to grab links from a certain webpage, but no matter what I do it won't grab from the /forums but only from minewind.com home page. No matter which url I ask to grab. I'm using a `requests` py library similar to urllib, I have tried this with urllib and it does something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are trying to access claims **it doesn't exist**:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://minewind.com/forums")
>>> r.status_code
404
```

This is probably due to user agent detection; if I set the User-Agent header to something resembling a real browser you do get a response:

```
>>> r = requests.get("http://minewind.com/forums",
...     headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.url
u'http://minewind.com/forums/'
>>> r.history
(<Response [301]>,)
```

You can see that you are redirected to a URL with the `/` at the end.

Comment: So can I pass along an appropriate header that will allow it through?

Comment: Also, the actual login payload isn't working, what constitutes what you need to define in the payload for logging in?

Comment: @Anthony: I guess you'd have to follow the login link, using a `requests.Session()` object to keep cookies, then posting login information to the form handler. It may be easier to use [robobrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle that interaction for you.

Comment: Well I really just need to know what information in a login process will be put in the dict and sent off? Is it the form ids? name? action? etc...

Comment: @Anthony: you'll have to study the HTML form; you can see what your browser actually sends in the developer tools. `robobrowser` parses that information out for you, automatically.